# Comparing performance to random in multiple choice test

Tags: expected-value

### Background TLDR

I was asked to grade some multiple choice tests. I noticed a difference between two groups (which differ by the part of our online materials they used). But I think it would be more meaningful to first subtract the performance of a randomly choosing participant, before I start theorising about the efficacy of teaching methods.

### My attempt

So, I assume the randomly choosing participant is a „well trained monkey“. It knows nothing and does not check for logical consistency in answers but has been trained to reliably follow the instructions of the test. The instructions said that, if you cross more than the indicated number of answers on a given segment, you get 0 points for this segment. So the monkey always chooses the right number of answers, albeit randomly.

- in this test there are two different types of questions. The type of question is always indicated on the sheet
- You have 11 questions with 3 choices (a,b,c) each. Only one each time is correct and yields 2 points
- You have 2 questions with 4 choices (a,b,c,d) each. Two each time are correct and each thereof yields 2 points. So maximum on such a question is 4

It seems to me, that the expectation value of the aforementioned monkey‘s performance is:

> $E = \frac{22}{3} + 2\times \frac{12}{6}= \frac{34}{3}$ ，

### Explanation of the second summand

For the two Questions with a quadruple of answers,
I can assume without loss of generality that the solution is ab and that the monkey chooses in an ordered fashion.

Total number of admissible choices: 6. This seems correct for it is $\binom{4}{2}$. Deriving it by foot:
There are 3 possible choices for the first letter.

- a leads to another 3 choices
- b leads to another 2 choices
- c leads to another 1 choice

Total number of admissible yielding choices with their yields:

- If a was the first choice, there are 2 choices that each yield of 2 and 1 that yields 4
- If b was the first choice, there are 2 choices that yield 2
- The remaining choice yields nothing.

### Question

**Have I erred? Is this a reasonable number for estimating the performance of randomly choosing participants as described above?** I could also use other indicators, such as the most probable performance of the monkey. I haven’t done such things in a long time and would be embarrassed to make suggestions based on my blunders.